# Unable to resume activity - Failure delivering result

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

My analytics are reporting the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException Msg: (Unable to resume activity
>   {com.NSouth.myapp/com.NSouth.myapp.Activity_Main}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=211, result=0, data=null} to activity

211 is a request code I use for an in-app purchase. Since my code is not referenced in the stacktrace, is there anything I can do about this?

Full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3089)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Seems like the return intent "data" is null. Use try and catch block!

Comment: @NiravRanpara, if that were the issue, would the stack trace not include a reference to my code where I try to use the data? If I can't handle it in my code, I would expect my code to be in the stack trace. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: i have searched and found this hope to be helpfull
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885517/failure-delivering-result-cannot-execute-non-void-method-opencamera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885517/failure-delivering-result-cannot-execute-non-void-method-opencamera)